# LINQ InvalidOperationException when calling ToList()

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I want to update records in a table in my database using the code below:

```
context.Events
        .Where(eventDb => !events.Any(@event => eventDb.Guid == @event.Guid))
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(eventDb => eventDb.IsCurrent = false);
```

But every time on calling ToList() I'm getting the following error, which isn't clear to me:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'event => EntityShaperExpression: 
    WawAPI.Models.Event
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
    IsNullable: False
.Guid == event.Guid' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are asking the SQL server to perform a `.Any()` operation on `events` which is presumably some sort of in-memory C# object and does not exist on the SQL server and is too complicated to be sent to SQL.

If you extract the Guids from `events` into a simple list of strings, then that could be simple enough to send to sql. You also need to change your linq query slightly, but I think this will give you the results you are looking for.

```
var eventGuids = events.select(a=>a.Guid).ToList();

context.Events
        .Where(eventDb => !eventGuids.Contains(event.Guid))
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(eventDb => eventDb.IsCurrent = false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that EventDb.Guid == @event.Guid can't be converted to the database raw SQL.
What type are the Guid's?
See what happens if you move the ToList() to before the Where clause.

Comment: It's not giving me an error if I move ToList() before the Where clause, but I don't understand why ```eventDb.Guid == @event.Guid``` would be a problem. Those are strings.